# Graviy Forms - gform_user_registration_update_user_id

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

This filter can be used to override which user is used to populate the form and updated when the form is submitted.

Case: 
Using gravity forms to update another user, update user base on `Email` field in another form, not currently logged.

[gform_user_registration_update_user_id](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_user_registration_update_user_id/)

We create form (`form id 12`) with 2 fields, email (`field id 1`) and userid (`field id 2`), we use email  (`field id 1`) to find `user ID` and save it in (`field id 2`) to pass to form (`form id 8`) to override `user ID` in it.

add to theme functions.php

```html
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_12', function( $form ) {
 $email = rgpost( 'input_1' );
 $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
 $userId = $user->ID;
 $_POST['input_2'] = $userId;
} );
```

We also set Regitration Gravity Forms add-on in (`form id 8`) to Update mode.

So now we have `user ID` and need to pass it to (`form id 8`), so we go to (`form id 12`) `Settings` - `Confirmation` and choose `Redirect` and place in `Redirect URL` path to form (`form id 8`), `Redirect Query String` checked and placed `userid={userid:2}`

So after (`form id 12`) submited we redirect to (`form id 8`) with userid=ID in url string, like:

`http://example.com/form8&userid=3`

Now we need to recieve userid on `form id 8`, we get it with `rgget` from url path since it already was added to it from redirect from `form id 12`

add to theme functions.php

```html
add_filter( 'gform_user_registration_update_user_id_8', 'override_user_id', 10, 4 );
function override_user_id( $user_id, $entry, $form, $feed ) {
$user_id = rgget( 'userid' );
return $user_id;
}
```

Also it changes `user ID` to update right profile on submit, with override `user ID`.

Thanks to gravity support i know how and what ^) best support ever. Hope it helps other people.